# VueJs - Prevent RouterView's Transitions on load for a carousel

Tags: javascript, css, typescript, vue.js, vuejs3

I'm currently learning VueJs (3), I've added a transition on my routes so my pages smoothly. It's working great and all, but the thing is that when I hit F5, or on first load, it plays the transition for the current page and it looks pretty bad.

The goal was to have my pages working like some kind of carousel.

I've inserted it that way in my App.vue

```
<script setup>
import {RouterView} from 'vue-router'
import Header from "@/components/Header.vue";
</script>

<template>
  <div class="absolute container min-w-full h-screen bg-blue-500 overflow-hidden">
    <Header/>
    <RouterView v-slot="{ Component, route }">
      <Transition :leave-active-class="route.meta.leaveClass" :enter-active-class="route.meta.enterClass">
        <component :is="Component"/>
      </Transition>
    </RouterView>
  </div>
</template>
```

And my routes looks that way:

```
  routes: [
    {
      path: '/',
      name: 'home',
      component: HomeView,
      meta: {
        leaveClass: "animate__animated animate__slideOutUp",
        enterClass: "animate__animated animate__slideOutUp"
      }
    },
    {
      path: "/about",
      name: 'about',
      component: () => import('../views/AboutView.vue'),
      meta: {
        leaveClass: "animate__animated animate__slideOutUp",
        enterClass: "animate__animated animate__slideOutUp"
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use as a workaround a landing page with no animations, and on refresh return to the landing page. It would require to changes the routes so the url never redirect to a new page and keep it in "/".